# LEFT OUTER JOIN Query filter by id

Tags: sqlite, left-join, outer-join

I am developing an android app and I am using CursorAdapter to show a TextView with a Name and a CheckBox if they have this item. My problem is to manage the cursor because as you can see sometimes names are duplicate.

I have two tables:

TABLE A:

```
_id | Name | Attend             
1 --- John ---- 1           
2 --- Peter --- 1               
3 --- Jean ---- 0               
4 --- Finn ---- 1               
5 --- Jake ---- 1
```

TABLE B:

```
_id | _idA | Item
12 --- 1 ---- Yogurt
21 --- 2 ---- Yogurt
33 --- 1 ---- Wine
25 --- 2 ---- KitKat
```

I am looking for a JOIN Table with these conditions:
Attend = 1 , Item = Yogurt and all the names in Table A without repeating, this is the result I am looking for:

```
Id |    Name    |   Attend  |   _id |   _idA | Item
1 -- John ----- 1 ----- 12 --- 1 --- Yogurt
2 -- Peter ---- 1 ------ 21 -- 2 --- Yogurt
4 -- Finn  ----- 1
5 -- Jake ----- 1
```

I am working with this query and I do not know if I am in the good way. I have tried to use Group by or WHERE Item = Yogurt, but I cannot find a solution to do not get names duplicate

```
SELECT * FROM TableA as A LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS B ON A._id = B._idA
```

And the result is:

```
Id |    Name    |   Attend  |   _id |   _idA | Item
1 -- John ---- 1 ------- 12 --- 1 --- Yogurt
1 -- John ---- 1 ------- 33 --- 1 --- Wine
2 -- Peter --- 1 ------- 21 --- 2 --- Yogurt
2 -- Peter --- 1 ------- 35 --- 2 --- KitKat
4 -- Finn ---- 1
5 -- Jake ---- 1
```

Comment: In the last output, look at the rows that you want to return. What values do they have in the `Item` column?

Comment: Hi CL. , those people could have another Item or even nothing, my table B is an Intermediate table

Answer (score 1):

You say you want the condition "Item = Yogurt", but that is not true.
The result you are looking for contains rows where the Item column has another value (NULL).

If you want to get the Finn/Jake rows, you must write a WHERE clause that matches those rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS B ON A._id = B._idA
WHERE A.Attend
  AND (B.Item = 'Yogurt' OR B.Item IS NULL);
```

Alternatively, put this condition into the outer join clause, where it will be ignored if there is no joined record:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB AS B ON A._id = B._idA
                           AND B.Item = 'Yogurt'
WHERE A.Attend;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! the first query do not show people when have bought items but the second one works perfectly.

Comment: These two queries behave identically. What specific row does not match?